# How to format DateTime in case of Nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to get `.Tostring()` Overloads for Nullable `Datetime?` ?

e.g

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

In Case of above Code i can format BirthDate.

But in case of below Code i can't get All Overloads of `.ToString()` method.

```
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

I am actually want to apply format to BirthDate in Razor Syntax ?

E.g

```
<li><b>BirthDate</b> : @Model.BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</li> // But this is not working.
```

**How to applying format for BirthDate in case of Nullable ?**

Comment: If a `Nullable<T>` has a value (check the `nullable.HasValue` property) you can get the `T` value using the `Value` property.

Comment: What do you want to return from ToString in case of a null value?

Comment: @Steve i am trying to apply some format to birthdate property in Razor  and the birthDate property is nullable i can't access `.ToString()` Overloads ? that what i am asking... i don't know my my question is down voted ?

Comment: Why don't you use DataAnnotations on your model?

Comment: @Steve i tried this one `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]` but it also not working...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [null-conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (available since C# 6.0).

```
string s = BirthDate?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This returns `null` if `BirthDate` has no value (is null), i.e. `ToString` will not be called in this case. If you want to return a text in this case instead, you can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
string s = BirthDate?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ?? "none";
```

or you can use the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (works with older C# versions)

```
string s = BirthDate.HasValue ? BirthDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "none";
```

or with the newer pattern matching (C# 7.0)

```
string s = BirthDate is DateTime d ? d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "none";
```

In Razor, apply this in parentheses (the `?` seems to confuse Razor):

```
<li><b>BirthDate</b> : @(Model.BirthDate?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))</li>
```

or

```
<li>
    <b>BirthDate</b> : @(BirthDate.HasValue ? BirthDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")
</li>
```

Comment: BirthDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'); i tried this in my Razor view but it's not working

Comment: I tested `(new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Now))?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` and `(new Nullable<DateTime>())?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` in the C# Interactive window. It works. Your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: in case you are working with a C# version older than 6.0, use the  ternary conditional operator.

Comment: I think you need to be sure to reference the correct roslyn compiler (like something from 2015 or later) as well to avoid runtime exceptions using C# 6.0 syntax.